# Nginx location matches

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

What is the difference between:

```
 location = /abc {}
```

and

```
 locaton ~ /abc {}
```

Comment: the second looks cooler :P (i think the first matches exact location and the second uses regular exp. but since im not sure i dont post this as an answer)

Answer (score 133, accepted):

`location = /abc {}` matches the exact uri `/abc`

`location ~ /abc` is a regex match on the uri, meaning any uri containing `/abc`,
you probably want: `location ~ ^/abc` for the uri begining with `/abc`
instead

Comment: You realise that you don't need a regex to match the start. That's nginx default operation with: `location /abc { ... }`

Comment: Just a quick "I second" on @dalore's comment. /abc exactly does what ~ ^/abc does (at least with my current version of nginx, 1.10.2 on centos). maybe it changed since this answer was written... further reading [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html)

Comment: Quick note, the previous statement is not accurate. `location /abc` will only match routes that begin with `/abc` or `/abc/`. That means it will match `/abc/def` but not `/abcdef`. The regex will match both since it matches on strings, not a routes..

Comment: Also `location /abc` will only match when no other location with a regular expression matches. So `location ~ ^/abc` takes precedence over `location /abc` even though it is defined later on: https://www.keycdn.com/support/nginx-location-directive.